# Formula to randomly assign names in a given group with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to create a formula in the below column `Assigned` so that a random name matching the same group as the current name is automatically inserted.

Names in the `Assigned` column must match the group of the current name and must not repeat throughout the list. I can't assign the current name with it's own name either. Any suggestions on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you use vba?

Comment: Ideally I want to be able to replicate this formula for Google Sheets so If I can use VBA for that then I guess so?

Comment: I think google sheets have their own scripting language for macros, so i believe vba can not be used.

Comment: Add a tag for google sheets so that any related person can easily fond the question.

Comment: Consider what happens when Harry gets fixed up with Lucy and Lucy with Harry. Then what happens to Lisa? I can come up with a formula that reaches a solution for the above table eventually (after pressing F9 a few times), but not really practical for larger numbers. I can post it if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is worth posting this. Although it might not be practical for large groups, it is a formula solution that works in Excel and Google sheets:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$8=B2)*($A$2:$A$8<>A2)*(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$8)=0),ROW($A$2:$A$8)-1),
RANDBETWEEN(1,SUM(($B$2:$B$8=B2)*($A$2:$A$8<>A2)*(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$8)=0)))))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Here is an example of a successful match:

[image]

and an unsuccessful one:

[image]

As you can see, Mike, Jack and Fred have paired up together leaving Dave on his own, likewise with Lucy and Harry.

In Excel you may have to press F9 a few times to get a successful result - in Google sheets you just have to keep changing something, or set it to update every minute while you make a cup of tea.

Comment: This is fantastic thank you! I'm trying to break down the formula and understand what you did here. I'm seeing if I can find out a way to adjust the listings to make sure the #NUM! errors can't happen. :)

Comment: How would I adjust your formula to include all names in column A instead of just A2-A8? This seems to work? `=INDEX($A$2:$A,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B=B2)*($A$2:$A<>A2)*(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,$A$2:$A)=0),ROW($A$2:$A)-1),
RANDBETWEEN(1,SUM(($B$2:$B=B2)*($A$2:$A<>A2)*(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,$A$2:$A)=0)))))`

Comment: Glad it works for you. Your whole-column formula also works fine in Google sheets. Good luck with the #NUM! errors - I don't think there is any simple way of preventing them. However, the ratio of successes to failures does seem to be fairly reasonable.

Comment: Do you think we can put a clause in the formula so that if it returns #NUM then to re run the formula? Once there are no #NUM left then it saves the assigned people to a separate column which will not change.

Comment: I think the short answer is'no'. You might be able to trigger the Calculate() method in Excel where the range contains #NUM! by using VBA, or re-calculate by enabling iterative calculation, but it would be completely different in Google sheets and you would lose the platform independence.

Answer (score 1):

It was my first time to work on something related to unique values, it took time but I learned lot from this question.

Answer of @Tom-Sharpe gave me an inspiration that it can be done, thanks to Tom for that. I tried and here it is.

I have checked it on some random data

```html
+------------+-------+-------------+------------+
| Name       | Group | RAND        | Assigned   |
| Malynda    | 1     | 0.644382728 | Boonie     |
| Boonie     | 1     | 0.167369621 | Venus      |
| Venus      | 1     | 0.547165865 | Malynda    |
| Jamal      | 2     | 0.193081046 | Cora       |
| Cora       | 2     | 0.399459181 | Jamal      |
| Alaster    | 2     | 0.910498559 | Enrika     |
| Enrika     | 2     | 0.45819549  | Melisandra |
| Melisandra | 2     | 0.612592303 | Alaster    |
| Petunia    | 3     | 0.957104883 | Lawton     |
| Mariam     | 3     | 0.602293619 | Grenville  |
| Caterina   | 3     | 0.695342797 | Mariam     |
| Stace      | 3     | 0.942926886 | Caterina   |
| Perle1     | 3     | 0.787227158 | Stace      |
| Lawton     | 3     | 0.315403693 | Perle1     |
| Grenville  | 3     | 0.515276361 | Petunia    |
| Elia       | 4     | 0.655404975 | Catarina   |
| Agosto     | 4     | 0.322045058 | Fidela     |
| Fidela     | 4     | 0.490635045 | Agosto     |
| Catarina   | 4     | 0.121053081 | Elia       |
| Elliot     | 5     | 0.994137138 | Eddie      |
| Mae        | 5     | 0.349103119 | Wadsworth  |
| Farleigh   | 5     | 0.645375865 | Mae        |
| Trudey     | 5     | 0.473849475 | Farleigh   |
| Gwenneth   | 5     | 0.678186154 | Trudey     |
| Wadsworth  | 5     | 0.254168853 | Gwenneth   |
| Eddie      | 5     | 0.02103249  | Elliot     |
| Denyse     | 6     | 0.294801945 | Fayina     |
| Tracie     | 6     | 0.113670327 | Denyse     |
| Aili       | 6     | 0.901562575 | Tracie     |
| Fayina     | 6     | 0.029515522 | Alain      |
| Mort       | 6     | 0.938536467 | Perle      |
| Alain      | 6     | 0.389741125 | Aili       |
| Perle      | 6     | 0.513800791 | Mort       |
| Mathew     | 6     | 0.972656521 | #N/A       |
| Benton     | 7     | 0.423710316 | Bret       |
| Bret       | 7     | 0.127478128 | Benton     |
| Mayne      | 7     | 0.701027869 | Kirbee     |
| Derry      | 7     | 0.564710572 | Marje      |
| Kirbee     | 7     | 0.510258205 | Derry      |
| Marje      | 7     | 0.600908601 | Mayne      |
| Devin      | 7     | 0.718740939 | #N/A       |
| Wilbert    | 8     | 0.763761013 | Griswold   |
| Brandice   | 8     | 0.482092682 | Marty      |
| Griswold   | 8     | 0.111418464 | Brandice   |
| Brandais   | 8     | 0.594020577 | Fair       |
| Kim        | 8     | 0.727863883 | Brandais   |
| Cam        | 8     | 0.858246187 | Kim        |
| Fair       | 8     | 0.640979168 | Wilbert    |
| Ardath     | 8     | 0.883008322 | Cam        |
| Marty      | 8     | 0.339506717 | Ardath     |
+------------+-------+-------------+------------+
```

D2 contains the below formula

```
=INDEX(
    $A$2:$A$51,
        MATCH(
            MIN(IF(
                    (COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$51)=0)*
                    ($B$2:$B$51=B2)*
                    ($A$2:$A$51<>A2),
                $C$2:$C$51)
                ),
            $C$2:$C$51,0)
    )
```

C2 contains just the RAND() function but it is pasted as values so that it doesn't update on every calculation, but if you want you can keep it as a function

There are some #N/A values returned by the formula, it arrives when there is no other person left that can be assigned.

Check it on your data and let me know if it working correctly.

Note that the formula is assuming that names are unique and are sorted based on the groups.

Comment: Wow this is fantastic! Great work! Can I ask how you paste the `RAND()` as values so they don't update each time?

Also I think to get around the unique name issue I can add another column as an ID and match and find the values by ID instead?

Comment: You can copy the cells and then paste them over existing cells, use paste special as values. step by step instructions can be different per different excel version, you can search google for details for your version if you could not found it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fluent with javascript you could attempt to use Google Apps Script to handle this by going to the toolbar `Tools` > `Script Editor`. Another way would be to record a macro via `Tools` > `Macros` > `Record Macro`. The script I generated via this method is below, however I couldn't figure out how to prevent assigning the current name with it's own name. My workaround for that is to select the range of assigned names in the same group and applying `Data` > `Randomize Range` until the assignment is satisfactory.

```
function AppendRandomNameByGroup() {
//Sort based on integer in group column
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1).sort({column: spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn() + 1, ascending: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();

  //Duplicate names to assigned names column
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:A1000').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();

  //Filter for each group and randomize items in 'assigned' column
  sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .setHiddenValues(['', '2', '3'])
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2:C1000').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('C4'));
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().randomize();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .setHiddenValues(['1', '', '3'])
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2:C1000').activate()
  .randomize();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .setHiddenValues(['2', '', '1'])
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2:C1000').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('C8'));
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().randomize();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
};
```

If you're trying to set-up a secret santa of some kind, another possible alternative to using scripts would be this Google Sheets Add-On that does something similar including the group functionality that you desire. However instead of assigning a recipient name in-sheet, it requires you to input corresponding e-mail addresses for each name and proceeds to email each participant with their assigned name.

[Secret Santa](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secret-santa/eoognkhkcdgmnhmlobgnehlpjmdcngkk?hl=en)

Sorry that this doesn't fit all your criteria.